# Drupal FAPI Error; Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to add some custom autocomplete functionality to a couple text fields on my user registration page, along the lines of this tutorial; http://drupal.org/node/854216.

I've been able to successfully accomplish that, but now whenever I submit the registration form I get a blank page, and this error shows up in the log;

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded
>   objects in /var/www/html/drupal/includes/common.inc on line 6448,
>   referer: http://[...]/drupal/?q=user/register

I can't find the topic now, but when I was initially googling this problem I read somewhere that this issue is typically that the '#' symbol has been added or missed from a property key. Because without a # symbol it treats the value of that property as a child, and thus an array. Or something along those lines, but after double checking it seems like all the properties I'm using should be as I've put them.

**Here is the code, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?**

```
function gtx_alterations_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['city/autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'city_autocomplete',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}

function gtx_alterations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['field_city_of_residence']['#type'] = 'textfield';
    $form['field_city_of_residence']['#title'] = t('City of Residence');
    $form['field_city_of_residence']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'city/autocomplete';
    $form['field_headquarters_location']['#type'] = 'textfield';
    $form['field_headquarters_location']['#title'] = t('Headquarters Location');
    $form['field_headquarters_location']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'city/autocomplete';
  }
}

function city_autocomplete($string = '') {
  $cities = array();
  $locations = array();
  $results = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.urlencode($string).'&type=adcity');

  $results = preg_replace('/\\\\u0*([0-9a-fA-F]{1,5})/', '&#x\1;', $results);

  preg_match_all('/"name":"[^,]+/', $results, $cities);
  preg_match_all('/"subtext":".+?,[^"]+/', $results, $locations);

  $final = array();

  foreach ($cities[0] as $key => $value) {
    $value = substr($value, 8);
    $subtext = substr($locations[0][$key], 11);
    $result = $value . ', ' . $subtext;

    $final[$result] = $result;
  }

  drupal_json_output($final);
}
```

---

**Some things I tried**

When trying to narrow down the problem I determined that commenting out these two lines;

```
$form['field_city_of_residence']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'city/autocomplete';
$form['field_headquarters_location']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'city/autocomplete';
```

removes the error, however that naturally means the autocomplete is also disabled.

---

Additionally replacing the contents of city_autocomplete($string) with

```
drupal_json_output(array('test' => 'test'));
```

does not resolve the error, meaning that the problem isn't something in the that function.

---

Removing the # symbol from these two lines

```
$form['field_city_of_residence']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'city/autocomplete';
$form['field_headquarters_location']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'city/autocomplete';
```

causes the previous error to be replaced with this one,

```
Unsupported operand types in /var/www/html/drupal/includes/form.inc on line 1755
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Field forms are bit confusing in Drupal 7, have a look at [Why is hook_form_alter so messy in d7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784) for a bit of a breakdown.

Suffice to say the actual HTML elements (the ones you want to change the values for) are found deeper in the array, e.g.

```
$form['field_city_of_residence'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#type'] = 'textfield';
$form['field_city_of_residence'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#title'] = t('City of Residence');
$form['field_city_of_residence'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'city/autocomplete';
```

Comment: That set up is pretty troublesome, especially considering it was otherwise working. Thanks a lot though. :)